# Identify UISearchBar with accessibility identifier during UITestCase

Tags: ios, xcode-ui-testing

I have one `UISearchBar` on my one of `UIViewController`.
But `UISearchBar` doesn't have accessibility identifier by default so I have tried to define manual accessibility identifier using "User Define Runtime Attribute".

[image]

But during `UITestCase` writing I can not access or identify `UISearchBar` by using "User Define Runtime Attribute". But I can't access it with identifier. I always have to go with placeholder text that I don't want to use because it causes issue while have "multi-language" support.

I have refer stack overflow answer regarding this issue, but none of them meet to my requirement.

Please help to provide solution for it. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In an application when I set the `accessibilityLabel` of my `UISearchBar` to `MySearchBar` using the User Define Runtime Attribute, if you look at the application's UI hierarchy you can see the following:

```
Attributes: Application, 0x604000198050, pid: 18393, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: 'MyApp'
Element subtree:
 →Application, 0x604000198050, pid: 18393, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}, label: 'MyApp'
    Window, 0x6000001993d0, Main Window, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
      Other, 0x604000199a50, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 736.0}}
        Other, 0x600000197aa0, traits: 8589934592, {{0.0, 20.0}, {414.0, 56.0}}, identifier: 'MySearchBar'
          Image, 0x604000198390, traits: 8589934596, {{0.0, 0.0}, {414.0, 76.0}}
          SearchField, 0x60000019a4e0, traits: 146031248384, {{8.0, 30.0}, {398.0, 36.0}}
```

That should give you an idea on how to find your searchbar. First search an element of type `other` that has the identifier that you set to the search bar, then find child of this element of type `searchBar`.

```
let searchField = XCUIApplication().otherElements["MySearchBar"].searchFields.firstMatch
searchField.tap()
searchField.typeText("Hello")
```

Comment: After a long search I got this Answer. Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this or a similar problem today.

I used to have a UISearchBar with accessibilityIdentifier set to "MySearchBar", and in turn the uisearchbar instance was set to the view controller's navigationItem.titleView. It worked well to find the input field for search like this

```
let inputSearch = XCUIApplication().otherElements["MySearchBar"]
```

When the UISearchBar was slightly moved like this: `navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem = UIBarButtonItem(customView: searchBar)` the above method of finding the element stopped working.

After a lot of trial and error this worked:

I set the placeholder of the search field (UISearchBar instance) like this:

```
searchBar.placeholder = "bla bla"
```

Then I could find the element in UI tests like this:

```
let inputSearch = XCUIApplication().searchFields["bla bla"]
```

So I stopped using accessibilityIdentifier for the UISearchBar in this case. This might have i18n problems, but anyways...